# Connecting HP ZR2440 screen via HDMI to MacBook Retina

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, hdmi, resolution, color

I connected an external HP ZR2440 screen via HDMI to a MacBook Pro Retina. Especially text seems not as sharp as with other (window) laptops. I found the color profile settings and found the default setting to be "HD 709-A". Switching to other profiles like Color-LCD looks better for text but worse for pictures.

Is there a default setting for this screen? If so, where can I find it? Do I have to download any driver to improve the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the mac settings in system preferences, then displays,
you can set it up so that there are two screens (duel screen). 
then run identify to make sure, open up colour and a box should open on both screens, then you will be able to calibrate each screen separate to your preferences.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What to you mean with "run identify" ?

Answer (score 0):

when you have multiple screens, you there will be an option to "identify" this will come up with the numbers 1,2,3 depending on how many screens you have. clicking on colour on the option should give you a calibrate option, so you can match the screens to your best fit